# Unable to install Ubuntu Desktop 14.04

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop when I try to run "Setup2.exe"  I will receive an error message which says "an error has occurred".  Based on this limited information what do I do find and correct the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using WUBI. WUBI has been deprecated since 13.04, you should do a normal install.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to burn the download either onto a USB or to a CD, and boot from that device.  Many people use USB for this purpose, so I have attached a link to the [instructions for making a bootable USB in Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to install with wubi, my recommendation is don't. just use the livecd to install and bypass the trouble of doing the install from within windows